# Enlarging Arrow Size in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

After pressing the button, the arrow I got is
something like this :

[image: Arrows]

Is there a way for me to increase the size of the arrow so that it is more visible? Thanks for any help.

```js
function ChangetoArrows() {
    var str = document.getElementById("Arrows").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace(/undefined|turn-right|turn-slight-left|turn-slight-right|turn-left/gi, function ChangetoArrows(x){
        
        if(x=='undefined'){return x='&uarr;';}
        if(x=='turn-right'){return x='&rarr;';}
        if(x=='turn-slight-right'){return x='&rarr;';}
        if(x=='turn-left'){return x='&larr;';}
        if(x=='turn-slight-left'){return x='&larr;';}
        
        else{return x;}//must need
    });
    
    document.getElementById("Arrows").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```css
.button4{
background-color: Yellow;
color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <button class="button4" onclick="ChangetoArrows()">ChangetoArrows</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML code renders as text so you can use `font-size` to adjust size.

Since it looks like you're putting these into an element with id `Arrows` you should be able to add this to your css:

```
#Arrows {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

`&rarr;` is an example of HTML unicode. Learn more here: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the font-size of button. for eg: `font-size:25px` and add in `.button4` class.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a CSS class to the element, which defines a larger font-size: `document.getElementById("Arrows").classList.add('big-arrows');`

Or you could use [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) arrows, which will be bolder than unicode arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap it with span and give css. checkout my snippet, hopefully it can help you in some way. have a nice day

```js
function ChangetoArrows() {
    var str = document.getElementById("Arrows").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace(/undefined|turn-right|turn-slight-left|turn-slight-right|turn-left/gi, function ChangetoArrows(x){

if(x=='undefined'){return x='&uarr;';}
if(x=='turn-right'){return x='&rarr;';}
if(x=='turn-slight-right'){return x='&rarr;';}
if(x=='turn-left'){return x='&larr;';}
if(x=='turn-slight-left'){return x='&larr;';}

else{return x;}//must need
});

    document.getElementById("Arrows").innerHTML = '<span class="arrow">'+res+'<span>';
}
```

```css
.button4{
background-color: Yellow;
color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow{
  font-size:150px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<button class="button4" onclick="ChangetoArrows()">ChangetoArrows</button>
<div id="Arrows">turn-right</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The others already answered the question, so I'm not going to repeat that. However, in this case I would recommend you to use [Material Design - Icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline):

```css
.material-icons.md-24 { font-size: 24px; }
.material-icons.md-34 { font-size: 34px; }
.material-icons.md-44 { font-size: 44px; }
.material-icons.md-54 { font-size: 54px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="material-icons md-24">arrow_back</i>
<i class="material-icons md-34">arrow_forward</i>
<i class="material-icons md-44">arrow_upward</i>
<i class="material-icons md-54">arrow_downward</i>
```

Just add the CSS library to your code and replace with JS like so:

`return x='<i class="material-icons md-24">arrow_back</i>';`